# The right way to migrate my question

Tags: support, migration

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39395808/interpolation-with-radial-basis-function-in-r), but the user [Hack-R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3604745/hack-r) suggested that the question is off-topic on SO, and would be on-topic on Cross Validated. I'm not sure, but he could be right. Also, I noted that the question got 2 "close and migrate to CV" votes, so I'm inclined to think he's right (sure, one vote may be from him, so I may be counting evidence twice :) but anyway, his suggestion makes sense).

I could just delete and repost on CV, but I read on Meta that you can also ask a moderator to migrate. Is this considered ok, or is it frowned upon as lazy? If it's ok, how do I find out who are the moderators, and how do I contact them? There's no *migrate* link below the question. I do see a *flag* link, though: should I use that?

PS I know the question may sound weird, because I could just delete and repost. I just wanted to play for once with SE features...of course, **if** that's considered ok. Otherwise, I won't. Actually, there's a good reason I would prefer to have the post migrated, instead than deleted and reposted. Since I'm not 100% sure it's more on-topic on CV than SO, if the post is migrated, it will be flagged as such on CV. This will prevent comments such as "this would really be more on topic on SO".

**EDIT**: since in meantime the question got another vote to close and migrate, and since the answer to this current question noted that it can take "time and effort" for the moderators to migrate the question, I deleted it and reposted it on Cross-Validated, and a moderator immediately put it on hold...Brilliant...so what should I do now with this question? Frankly it just doesn't make to say that it's off-topic on *both* sites.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I could just delete and repost on CV

Yes, that option is available to you as long as no one has posted an answer. If an answer has been posted, you should not delete the question, because it will take their answer with it. That isn't nice; they probably worked hard on that answer, and it should follow the question. I forget the exact rules, but I believe if their answer has been upvoted at least once, the system will prevent you from deleting the question for this exact reason.

Comments to a question never block deletion. If the comments are valuable <sup><sub>(Nitpicker's Corner: Some people believe that comments are *never* valuable by their very nature. I really don't want to get such unvaluable comments on this answer.)</sub></sup>, you might want to migrate. Most of the time, they're just noise and would be rendered obsolete by a migration (like comments that suggested migration!), so you shouldn't worry about that.

If the system blocks you from deleting the question because there are answers, your only recourse would be to flag and ask a moderator to delete it. Which brings us to…

> I read on Meta that you can also ask a moderator to migrate.

That is correct. Except for a few "blessed" targets, a moderator is required to migrate a question to another Stack Exchange site. A moderator can migrate a question in a single stroke.

The other alternative is getting 3 users with close-vote privileges to vote for your question to be migrated. Although this only works for the unlocked migration paths (and only for recent questions that are less than 60 days old), Cross Validated is one of those. In fact, [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39395808/interpolation-with-radial-basis-function-in-r) has already received 2 votes in favor of its migration there.

In these special cases, the community can take care of migration itself, without the need for a moderator's intervention. The cases are currently:

- Meta (this site)
- Super User
- TeX
- DBA
- Stats

> If it's ok, how do I find out who are the moderators, and how do I contact them? There's no migrate link below the question. I do see a flag link, though: should I use that?

Yes, any time you want to contact a moderator, you use the flag link. There is no "migration requested" flag, so you will need to use the option that allows you to type a custom message ("it needs ♦ moderator attention"). Use that box to explain *why* you think your question needs to be migrated, and to which site you want it to be migrated. (Using the full name is best: CV => Cross Validated.)

> Is this considered ok, or is it frowned upon as lazy?

No, it's perfectly okay, and it's certainly not lazy. The only concern is that the question you're asking to be migrated *might not be appropriate* for the other site. In order to keep one site from becoming another site's garbage dump, moderators will typically want to get feedback from the moderators of the target site *first*, before migrating a question. (Unless it is blindly obvious that it is (A) a high-quality question, and (B) obvious that it is on-topic for that other site.) Obtaining that confirmation takes time and effort, so you should only flag a question for migration when you are absolutely certain that it is appropriate.

> This will prevent comments such as "this would really be more on topic on SO".

Yeah… These comments are actually somewhat problematic. This case is a good example. As I pointed out, the community can migrate any question they think is appropriate to Cross Validated *without any interaction from the person who asked the question* (you). So leaving the comment "should be migrated to CV" actually results in confusion. You see the comment, think it means you should do something, but can't figure out what to do. What Hack-R should have done (and probably what he already *did* do) is simply cast a vote for migration. There is no need for a comment. Either the community will agree with them, and after 2 more votes, the migration will happen automatically, *or* no one else thinks the question should be migrated, and his vote silently ages away—no noise, no fuss.

Another problem with comments recommending migration is that the users making the recommendations may not be familiar with the guidelines and policies of the other site, resulting in a situation where they are giving *bad advice*. The question actually *shouldn't* be migrated, either because it would be off-topic on the suggested site, or because it's just a bad question and should be closed outright, not dumped off anywhere else.

I don't mean to call Hack-R out specifically here. *Lots* of users do this with perfectly good intentions, and although it's been discussed before *ad nauseam*, there's really no way to get the message out that it should stop. So, sorry for the confusion.

---

In general, though, keep in mind that just because a specialized site exists where a question might be on-topic does not necessarily mean that it is off-topic for another site. Said differently: the scope of two sites can overlap. It's perfectly reasonable to ask R programming questions on Stack Overflow, just like it might *also* be reasonable to ask them on Cross Validated. You can ask Ubuntu questions on both Super User and on Ask Ubuntu, and possibly also on Unix/Linux.

When there are multiple sites on which a question can be asked, it's ultimately up to *you*, the asker, to decide which site you want to ask it on. Different communities are different. Pick the one you think is most appropriate for your question, and from whose members you think you'll get the best answer.