# How to migrate a question to Mathematics

Tags: support, migration

I recently ran across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41493032/does-x-y0-implies-anything-about-maximum-eigen-values) question, which is off-topic for this site. However, it may be on topic for the mathematics site, depending on their rules.

Unfortunately, the migration flag only has a few targets, none of which are mathematics. The rationale for this is apparently explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options?rq=1).

So, how do I correctly ask for a question to be migrated to a site not on that list?

My understanding from looking at [these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) [posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334195/the-right-way-to-migrate-my-question) is that I should raise a moderator flag and explain what I'm trying to do. Is this correct?

I apologize, almost certainly a duplicate of those above.

Comment: Are you sure that the question is quality on the site you want to migrate it to?

Comment: No tbh. If I understand correctly, each SE site has its own criteria, is it up to the migrator to look at them and make that decision?

Comment: What I would do in your shoes is "close" -> "off-topic" -> "blatantly off-topic (nothing to do with programming)".

Comment: Or you could choose "in need of moderator attention" and write "this question belongs in a community not listed in the close options: <LINK TO THE COMMUNITY>". (As a general rule; from the comments here, it appears that this particular question should not be migrated.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't know for sure post is on-topic on other site and high enough quality for the target site it is generally bad idea to ask for migration.

For the particular question I strongly suspect it will be not welcome on any of SE sites (including suggested Math.SE) due to "no research shown".

Since the question is clearly off-topic on SO voting to close is right approach (i.e. with custom reason "... about algebra and nothing to do with programming" as @giusti suggested in comment). You may consider downvote as "shows no research" is not directly tied to question being on-topic or not. You can leave comment for OP to consider posting on other site - make sure to highlight that OP should review target site rules first.